# Add number from the previous amount in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I Am trying to create a simple Point of Sales using C#, The user asks to select product with price along with it and required to input the quantity they want to purchase. After that, the system will ask the user if they want to purchase another product, as the user selects yes, I want to add the amount of product purchased from the previous transaction (price*qty) and the amount purchased from the new transaction.If the user finally selected NO, the system will show the overall total amount of products purchased using Message box. I am thinking about looping but I have no idea where to start with it.Any suggestions will be appreciated.Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    priceData = double.Parse(txtPR.Text);
    qty = double.Parse(txtQty.Text);

    answer = priceData * qty;

    lblTotal.Text = "You have to pay " + answer.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("You have to pay a total of:" + answer.ToString());
    writeFile();

    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to buy other products?", "BUY", 
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

    }

    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for shopping! Kindly get your receipt.");                        
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\Add\Receipt.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would really suggest that you remove the `try` from your code. What exception are you expecting to catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the current design methodology for your application, with application logic occurring directly in the UI (look into 'MVC' if you'd like an idea of this). Nevertheless there is a fairly easy way to accomplish what you're asking.

In your `Form` class, add a new property called `Subtotal`. You can use this to persist the value

For example:

```
public partial class YourFormName : Form
{
    double Subtotal;
}
```

Now in your method:

```
try
{
    priceData = double.Parse(txtPR.Text);
    qty = double.Parse(txtQty.Text);
    answer = priceData * qty;

    Subtotal += answer;

    lblTotal.Text = "You have to pay " + Subtotal.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("You have to pay a total of:" + Subtotal.ToString());
    writeFile();
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to buy other products?", "BUY", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if(result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Subtotal = 0;
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for shopping! Kindly get your receipt.");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\Add\Receipt.txt");
    }
}
```

This keeps track of the `answer` values by adding it to a subtotal. When the user refuses to buy other products (`DialogResult.No`), the main form will be activated again. At this point the user inputs new quantity/price, and must activate the event to update the `Subtotal` again.

As you said, you can alternatively use loops, but these loops would have to launch new UI windows to capture the new quantity and price.

Because I can't see the rest of your code, I assumed that your method is called directly by an 'update' button click event or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to envelope your "asking" code in a loop, which condition is the result of the MessageBox.

It would be along the line of:

```
[Initialize the variables]
qtyPrd1 = 0;
pricePrd1 = 0;

qtyPrd2 = 0;
pricePrd2 = 0;
...

[Main loop]
do {

[Present the user the products]
[Get the choice (product, quantity)]

[Add the value to the product variable]
if (choice == 1)
    qtyPrd1++;
if (choice == 2)
    qtyPrd2++;

subtotal = qtyPrd1 * pricePrd1 + qtyPrd1 * pricePrd2 + ...;
[Present the subtotal]

} while (result == DialogResult.Yes);

[Compute total]
total = qtyPrd1 * pricePrd1 + qtyPrd1 * pricePrd2 + ...;
[Present total result of cart]
```

Note that the [] are just comments, refer to your current code to fill the blanks, you have all you need.